# Is "for" in label tag targetable via CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, label

I'm wondering if the "for" in the label tag is targetable via CSS? I'm trying to style a plugin via css in Wordpress and cannot access the HTML.

Below is an example code but if there was a label tag with 'class' and a 'for'...can I target this specific line using the 'for' somehow? Reason why I'm asking is I need to individually target lines and using just the label and class won't allow me.

I'm not the best at html/css so I could be wrong but...

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by targeting attributes? CSS refers to elements. And what is “this specific line”?

Comment: Trying it would have give you the answer. Just like input[type=text] where type is an attribute, label[for=abcdefg]

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do using [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
label[for]{
    /*Rules here*/
}
```

and if for specific value:

```
label[for="male"]{
     /*Rules here*/
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aStXm/)**

Comment: I just never thought of that. This is so obvious. That was usefull.